# platformio No such file or directory problem

Tags: c++, platformio

So I wanted to create a project, but when I tried to add a simple header file (adp.h), use quick fix to add this line: `"${workspaceFolder}/lib/boot/headers"` to  `c_cpp_properties.json` and build the project, builder does not even find this file.
It seems strange to me, because three days earlier, when I was using this method to add header files the builder was building my older projects flawlessly.

adp.h do not contain anything

[editor setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzFhw.png)

Building message:

```
Processing teensy41 (platform: teensy; board: teensy41; framework: arduino)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/teensy/teensy41.html
PLATFORM: Teensy (4.12.0) > Teensy 4.1
HARDWARE: IMXRT1062 600MHz, 512KB RAM, 7.75MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (jlink) External (jlink)
PACKAGES:
 - framework-arduinoteensy 1.153.0 (1.53)
 - toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi 1.50401.190816 (5.4.1)
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> http://bit .ly/configure-pio-ldf
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 90 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\teensy41\src\main.cpp.o
Compiling .pio\build\teensy41\FrameworkArduino\AudioStream.cpp.o
Compiling .pio\build\teensy41\FrameworkArduino\Blink.cc.o
Compiling .pio\build\teensy41\FrameworkArduino\DMAChannel.cpp.o
src\main.cpp:2:17: fatal error: adp.h: No such file or directory

*************************************************************
* Looking for adp.h dependency? Check our library registry!
*
* CLI  > platformio lib search "header:adp.h"
* Web  > https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=header:adp.h
*
*************************************************************

compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I tried to find `adp.h` by google 'arduino header "adp.h"' but I didn't find anything with sense. Where does it come from / belongs to? Maybe, you didn't set the include paths properly? Btw., what do you mean with this statement: _adp.h do not contain anything_? Why all the trouble if it doesn't contain anything?

Comment: @Scheff's Cat  I created an example of a problem, which occured in a project that contained code in a header file. Anyway i solved my problem i just added this line  to platform.ini file ` lib_extra_dirs = C:\Users\Butte\Desktop\coding\testing\lib\boot ` and it compiled correctly.